# init NSData to nil SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

How can I init NSData to nil ?

Because later, I need to check if this data is empty before using UIImageJPEGRepresentation.

Something like :

```
if data == nil {
    data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)
}
```

I tried data.length == 0 but I don't know why, data.length isn't equal to 0 while I haven't initialized.

Comment: You mean `nil` or empty data? That's a very different thing.

Comment: I suppose I mean empty data.

Comment: You demonstrate precisely how to test to see if `data` (which must be an optional) is `nil` or not. And if this optional hasn't been set to anything, then it already is `nil`. If you want to explicitly set it to `nil`, just do so, e.g. `data = nil`. So I don't understand "how can I init `NSData` to `nil`?" question.

Comment: Maybe you want to use an optional? Please show us how you're declaring data, and where you're trying to assign to it. In swift, something of type NSData can never be nil. If you want it to be able to be nil, it should be type NSData?

Comment: I don't think you mean "empty data". That doesn't make sense in the context of a JPEG representation. Either there is data (and therefore its `length` would not be `0`), or it's `nil`.

Comment: My data is an optional attribute of my data model : @NSManaged var mydata: NSData. I download mydata of the image at an URL in a tableview. I need to check mydata because if it's not empty, image has been already downloaded, so no need to redownload it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One thing you can do is ensure your `NSData` property is an optional. If the NSData object has not been initialized yet, then you can perform your `if nil` check.

It would look like this:

```
var data: NSData? = nil
if data == nil {
    data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)
}
```

Because optionals in Swift are set to nil by default, you don't even need the initial assignment portion! You can simply do this:

```
var data: NSData? //No need for "= nil" here.
if data == nil {
    data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want a nil `NSData`, then you can initialize it like this:

```
var data: NSData?
```

Then you can use:

```
if data == nil {
    data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)
}
```

If you are wanting empty data, then initialize it like this:

```
var data = NSData()
```

And to check that it is empty:

```
if data.length == 0 {
    data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)
}
```

Comment: FYI, In the first line, you don't need the `= nil` part. It will initialize to `nil` by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set your `data` variable to `nil`, just do `data = nil`. If you want to set it to be empty, then do `data = NSData()`.